# Variable of field declared void error?

Tags: c++, class, void

Here is the whole code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

enum poz {Vraboten,Direktor,Shef};

class Vraboten{
private:
    char name[100];
    int plata;
    poz pozicija;
public:
    Vraboten();
    Vraboten(char *n,int p, poz pz)
    {
        strcpy(name,n);
        plata=p;
        pozicija=pz;
    }
    ~Vraboten();
    void setName (const char *n)
    {strcpy(name,n);}

    void setPlata (int p)
    {plata=p;}

    void setPozicija(poz pz)
    {pozicija=pz;}

    const char* getName(){return name;}
    const int getPlata() {return plata;}
    void getPozicija (){
    switch(pozicija){
    case 0:cout<<"Vraboten";
    case 1:cout<<"Direktor";
    case 2:cout<<"Shef";
    default:cout<<"Invalid entery";
    }}


};
void Sort(Vraboten emp[],int br);

int main()
{
    Vraboten vrab[100];
    char ime[100];
    int payment,pozition;
    int broj,i;
    cout<<"Vnesi broj na vraboteni";
    cin>>broj;
    for(i=0;i<broj;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Vnesi ime na vraboten broj "<<i<<" ";
        cin>>ime;
        cout<<"Vnesi plata na vraboten broj "<<i<<" ";
        cin>>paymen;
        cout<<"Vnesi pozicija na vraboten broj "<<i<<" 0-Vraboten, 1-Direktro, 2-Shef";
        cin<<pozition;
       vrab[i].setName(ime);
       vrab[i].setPlata(paymen);
       vrab[i].setPozicija(poz(pozition));

       }
       Sort(vrab,broj);
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {

cout << i + 1 << ". " << vrab [i]. getName () << "\t"
<< vrab [i]. getPlata () << "\t"
<< vrab [i]. getPozicija () << endl ;

}

}
void Sort(Vraboten emp[],int br)
{
    int i,j;
    Vraboten temp;
    for(i=0;i<br;i++)
        for(j=i;j<br;i++)
    {
        if(emp[i].getPlata()<emp[j].getPlata())
        temp=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
    }
}
```

And it gives me an error: Variable of field 'Sort' declared void, in line 42 the declaration of Sort just before main. I really don't know what this means? I'm waiting for a quick reply. And i know the post is not that well edited, but i don't have much time so if you know reply.

Comment: Use `std::string` for the sake of your sanity.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `break` in those `switch` cases?

Comment: -1 for "i know the post is not that well edited, but i don't have much time".  If you can't be bothered to take a minute to tidy up your post, why should others struggle through it to help you for free?

Comment: try to learn good syntax formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is due to there being two things in the global namespace called `Vraboten`:

```
enum poz {Vraboten,Direktor,Shef};
//        ^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
class Vraboten{
//    ^^^^^^^^
```

You need a way to disambiguate these two `Vraboten`s. If you are using C++11 you can declare the `enum` as an `enum class`:

```
enum class poz {Vraboten,Direktor,Shef};
```

If you do this you will have to change the references to the values of this enum to `poz::Vraboten`, `poz::Direktor`, and `poz::Shef`.

If you don't have a compiler that supports C++11 you can emulate this by wrapping the enum declaration in a namespace:

```
namespace poz {
    enum poz {Vraboten,Direktor,Shef};
}
```

As above you will have to prefix the `enum` values with `poz`, but also when declaring a variable of this `enum` type you will have to use `poz::poz myVar`.

Comment: Yeah that did it, i would have never looked there for an error. Thanks.